# how to stop response or data downloading from salesforce in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, salesforce

I have database on salesforce site. I have used zksforce api to interact from iphone application.

Problem:
1. when we send request to salesforce i am displaying small loading screen which has small cancel button to cancel downloading

1. Can anybody suggest me possible ways to implement cancel functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a boolean flag in your code which is false by default and you change it to true when urser clicks the cancel button. Now every time you send a request to salesforce you can check the state of the flag and only send the request if it's false but be careful to set it back to false when user makes a new request.

Hope this help you.